# Change href for a div class based on screen size without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to change an href based on the screen size, This is what I've tried based on my research

My JS isn't great so I figure i'd ask

```js
var productLink = document.getElementsByClassName('productlink');

function changeLink() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1025) {
    productLink.setAttribute('href', "product-page-mobile.html");
  }
  else {
    productLink.setAttribute('href', "product-page-desktop.html");
  }
}

changeLink();
window.addEventListener('resize', changeLink);
```

edit:

Tried

```js
var productLink = document.getElementsByClassName('productlink');
for(var i = 0; i < productLink.length; i++)


function changeLink() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1025) {
    productLink.setAttribute('href', "product-page-mobile.html");
  }
  else {
    productLink.setAttribute('href', "product-page-desktop.html");
  }
}

changeLink();
window.addEventListener('resize', changeLink);
```

Still doesn't work :(

Edit:
This works.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('productlink'), function(productLink) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1025) {
        productLink.setAttribute('href', "product-page-mobile.html");
      }
      else {
        productLink.setAttribute('href', "product-page-desktop.html");
      }
});
```

Comment: Try `var productLink = document.querySelector('.productlink')` to get just the first element with that class name

Comment: Personally, I'd have multiple `<a>` elements for each screen-size and show / hide them with CSS media queries

Comment: Please learn to use your browser's developer console to look for errors. FYI, your `for` loop does nothing and changes nothing regarding the rest of your code

Comment: I cant use media querys because the link is in an image, and in order to do that I would have to load 3x4 images because media querys don't prevent the image from loading. It would severely effect my pages load speed.

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: var productLink = document.querySelector('.productlink') doesn't work and edited code doesn't work either :(